Running .NET Framework 4.7 DLLs in a Docker Container on Windows
I have an application for which I only have the compiled DLL files, but I do not have the source code. Is it possible to add the DLL's into a Docker container and run them using .NET Framework 4.7 on Windows?

A .dll file isn't an application, it's a library. You need the .exe to run a program, and it maybe uses the dll as part of it.
